# Systematic means of transcribing words to vowel/consontant patterns

Tags: vowels, consonants

Looking for a systematic online step-by-step process to codify English words into vowel/consontant patterns (CVC, CVCe, CVVC, etc.) and the correct sound (long-vowel, short-vowel, blend, diagraph, etc.).

Comment: Written words in ASCII, or spoken words in an audio format? "English words" means the latter, unless you specify more clearly. And which kinds of vowel and consonant are you looking for? Phones? Phonemes? Allophones? Syllables? There are a lot of things you could be asking for, some of which clearly don't exist, with others that clearly do.

Comment: @jlawler: "Dictionary notation" to CVC, beyond that I'd say the symbols should be limited to get would be found if you used a dictionary style rendering of word sounds; if you'd like it limit it to one online dictionary, that's find. Basically I'm not even able to find an online dictionary that would let me query the 40k common words in English, so I'm attempting to make my own. Beyond that, I'm unable to find a notation standard, for example "crop" is CVC, and not CCVC. Let me know if that was of any help, since if I knew the answer to you questions, I wouldn't be asking the question. Thanks!

Comment: OK, then **don't** use an American dictionary. The sound symbols should be either IPA or K&K, and American dictionary publishers think Americans are too stupid to use these, so they still use Webster's 18th-Century non-phonetic system. 

With one exception, maybe. K&K standard notation is an English phonemic system used in Kenyon & Knott's *Pronouncing Dictionary of English*, published 1953 by Merriam-Webster. It gives **just** the phonemic transcription of most common words.

Comment: @jlawler: Yes, I know. If you're able to create an answer that uses IPA and supports converts to "dictionary notation" that's fine. So, is what I'm looking for clear now?

Comment: The cheapest way would be to scan K&K and then do OCR. It'd take a lot of training, but unless K&K is online, which I doubt, it's the only way to get that information electronically.

Comment: @jlawler: Ha, that's the first time I've ever heard anyone say that mining non-digital unstructured data would be the cheapest way to do something, may I ask why you believe this to be the case. Also, feel free to post you reply as an answer, since it appears you believe it the answer; which is what it is.  +1 to all you comments, and your effort to help me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you are asking for is a problem encountered in text-to-speech systems and is called **grapheme-phoneme-conversion**. A system performing this task takes an english word and translates it to a phonetic transcription. If you search for this on Google you will find information how it is done and there are even some freely available systems for this task,  I didn't find one that works online though. If you want CVC instead of a phonetic transcription, it should be a simple replacement task from there.

About your data problem: To get a list of frequent english words have a look at the 1-Grams at [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets) or get an english [wordlist](http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html) and  [sort it by word frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764229/sort-words-by-their-usage). If you are interested in dictionary entries, you can look up the words in Wikipedia afterwards.

All in all this is a task which can be done, but you probably won't solve it if you don't have a little experience in programming, as I doubt that there are online tools which do exactely what you want to do.

Comment: PS: if you are working with NLP-tasks more often you should have a look at http://bit.ly/u4lZUG.

Comment: Thanks, main problem is not data or mapping the transformation, it's finding a standard for the transformation. I have yet to find specs for CVC pattern notation from any source. Thanks for posting an answer, since I'm aware this a  none standard topic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the Area51 NLP exchange later, though this is really more of a token transformation issue than a language processing problem in my opinion; meaning the task is a simply transcribing via a standard method from one form to another, though might be wrong.

Comment: FYI in rereading your answer, getting phonetic transcriptions is not the issue; example, Google "[define: phonetic](http://www.google.com/search?q=define:+phonetic)". The issue is a schema for a phonetic notation, for example
Google's to CVC notation. Again, thanks for the input!

Comment: yes, but it will be much easier to derive a CVC notation from a phonetic notation than from normal text. so if you don't find a better way you might want to go around that corner.

Comment: about the schema.. any grapheme-phoneme-conversion has kind of a schema (e.g. rules) 'inside'. maybe you find a good answer in some papers on google scholar which discuss grapheme-phoneme-conversion

Comment: Right, Google provides a broad phonetic notation, and the source word would have to be processed in parallel I believe to account for example the CVC notation "CVCe". Suggestion of parse the Google N-Gram for frequency is one point. Guessing starting with a narrow IPA database would be the best idea, though I've can't recall every seeing a public one before that covers large surface area.